# Outside electric panel, does it require another housing?

Tags: electrical-panel

We are upgrading the electric panel.  The current one is attached to the outside of the house. The new one will be in the same place but will be a bigger panel and supports 200 Amps. Do I need to protect the panel in any way from the elements?  Is the metal panel enclosure adequate enough?

Will it benefit from additional protection?

Answer (score 4):

You will need an outdoor-rated panel enclosure for this task (NEMA 3R is typical vs. the NEMA 1 rating on an indoor panel).  Most major manufacturers (I know Square-D and Eaton do this) provide panelboards in NEMA 3R enclosures as standard catalog items in their light-duty panelboard lines.